# subdomain nginx and angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, nginx, angular-ui-router

I'm building a sort of e-commerce in AngularJS.

All the stores are referenced by a unique string (mystore, store2, etc) and to see their products you have to go to: *example.com/#/**mystore**/products or example.com/#/**store2**/products*

What i would  like to do now is to set up a nginx rewrite so that **mystore** can be accessed by

```
mystore.example.com/products
```

instead of

```
example.com/#/mystore/products
```

Sort of how slack is doing for his customers

Is this possible ?

I tried with this configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(.*?).example.com;
    location / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass http://example.com/#/$1;
    }
}
```

The problem now is that this applies also to the scripts files and so

```
mystore.example.com/scripts/main.js
```

now points to

```
example.com/#/scripts/main.js
```

and of course nothing is found and the app doesn't work. Is there a way to do it only for the angular param and not for everything else ?

Answer (score 1):

Add additional nested route to filter such cases

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(.*?).example.com;
    location / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass http://example.com/#/$1;

       location ~* ^/(scripts|static|images) {
          proxy_pass http://example.com/;
       }
    }
}
```